# Mysql TRIM not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to cleanse my numbers in my database by using :

```
update valuations set Telephone = TRIM(Telephone) where  1 = 1
```

but 0 rows are effected and all the nunmbers still have a space in them. The datatype is varchar so im unsure why this isn't working - can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL [TRIM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) Function - Remove __leading__ and __trailing__ spaces

Comment: Are your spaces at the beginning and end of your string ? If so, `TRIM()` should remove them. If they are in the middle of your string, though, you'd better use `REPLACE()`.

Comment: `trim()` does not remove spaces from in a string, for example take this string: `trim(" Hello World ")` this becomes: `"Hello World"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi pandemic please use

UPDATE valuations SET Telephone = REPLACE(Telephone, ' ', '') WHERE 1 = 1;

Hope this works pal

Answer (score 6):

As I said in my comment, I'm guessing your spaces are in the middle of your entries, `TRIM` won't work then. Use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) instead :

```
UPDATE valuations SET Telephone = REPLACE(Telephone, ' ', '') WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

`trim()` will remove only those spaces at the ends of a string. If you want to remove those inside the string, use [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html):

```
UPDATE valuations SET Telephone = REPLACE(Telephone, ' ', '') where  1 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You should first trim string and after that replace space with empty character:

```
update valuations set Telephone = REPLACE(TRIM(Telephone), ' ', '') where  1 = 1
```

`TRIM` function is useful when you need to remove other blank characters from begining and end of string, for example new line character or TAB.

More about `TRIM()` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: there is no point of using `trim` now, when you are removing all spaces anyway

Comment: Yes, but when you have other blank characters, TRIM will be useful.